# Циклы в C.

Tags: c, циклы

Такой вопрос. Если несколько циклов вложены друг в друга, и в одном из них вдруг выполняется break; "ломается" только один цикл, или все?

Comment: Прерывает текущий цикл, один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ломается, а прекращается не зависимо от условия... только непосредственно тот в котором выполнился break;

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Слово "ломается" я напмисал в кавычках, у меня еще оказывается кнопка западает.

Answer (score 1):

[[@RDSk](/users/19866/rdsk)](/users/19866/rdsk), не то, что бы я был противником подобных вопросов, но IMHO набить 10 строк

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main () {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (j == 2)
          break;
      }
      puts("only one");
    }
    return puts("Bye") == EOF;
  }
```

и проверить гипотезу быстрее, чем дождаться ответа.

--

Для выхода из нескольких циклов используйте `goto LABEL;`

(только аккуратно. Это должен быть Эээ... "структурный" *goto*).